# Installing Ruby Gems behind a Proxy

Tags: ruby, installation, firewall, rubygems

It appears this topic has been covered a few times before, but those solutions have only gotten me so far.  I now have my sources properly updated and I am able to query for gems without an error but I keep getting empty results for my searches.

I installed rubysspi and copied over the spa.rb file as mentioned in the readme.

The readme also suggested using this line which did not work for me based on my install path:

```
ruby -rspa 'C:\Program Files\ruby\gem' list --remote sspi
```

So I switched it to my install directory off the root:

```
ruby -rspa 'C:\ruby\gem' list --remote sspi
```

But that also didn't work so a search for the gem file located it in the bin directory so this command finally worked for me:

```
ruby -rspa 'C:\ruby\bin\gem' list --remote sspi
```

But I got empty results back:

```
*** REMOTE GEMS ***
```

SO I tried other gems and had the same results.  Then I listed my gem sources and rubygems is listed as expected.  Am I missing something else?

```
c:\ruby>gem sources

*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never ended up getting gems to install behind my company's proxy.  Instead I ended up downloading the gems directly and then installing them from my local downloads folder.

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable `http_proxy` to the `http://host:port` of your proxy server.

Comment: I hadn't tried that variation of the environment variable but it still did not fix the issue.

Comment: Strangely this does not work for me, I am using ruby 2.0.0p481

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

sudo HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080" gem install bundler

Replace "10.3.100.207" with your host and "8080" with your "port value"

It worked for me.

Or try this:

sudo HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080"
or 
sudo export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.3.100.207:8080"

Also do with https and HTTPS as I faced problem once due to this.